# How to get the publisher name from a received message in rospy?

Tags: ros, rospy, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody,

I can't find anywhere how to get the publisher name from a received message using python. In C++ I just have to do the following:

```
void
callback( const ros::MessageEvent< cola2_common::BhResponse const >& event )
{
    const std::string& publisher_name = event.getPublisherName() ;
}
```

What's the equivalent in python? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10346/how-to-get-the-publisher-name-from-a-received-message-in-rospy?/) by [pparescasellas](https://answers.ros.org/users/693/pparescasellas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Connection_Information

---

Edit (by @jayess ):

Just so you don't have to go clicking around for the answer (from @bhaskara's link):

> A subscriber can get access to a
> "connection header", which includes
> debugging information such as who sent
> the message, as well information like
> whether or not a message was latched.
> This data is stored as the
> `_connection_header` field of a received message.
>
> e.g.

> ```
> print m._connection_header
> ```

```
{'callerid': '/talker_38321_1284999593611',
 'latching': '0',
 'md5sum': '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1',
 'message_definition': 'string data\n\n',
 'topic': '/chatter',
 'type': 'std_msgs/String'}
```

> We do not recommend using `callerid`
> information beyond debugging purposes,
> as it can lead to brittle code in an
> anonymous publish/subscribe
> architecture.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-02**:
@jayess: I've merged your additional answer with the one by @bhaskara.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-02**:
@gvdhoorn, great. Even better than two answers.